# What does the System.Drawing.Color class look like?

Tags: c#, class

I had a question about handling Gender class and looks like someone else has already asked the question and got an answer.
[Best way to represent Gender in a class library used in multilingual applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722236/best-way-to-represent-gender-in-a-class-library-used-in-multilingual-application)

The answer is to mimic the System.Drawing.Color class. Where can I see how this class is structured?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the answer...  use reflector....

Comment: Or JetBrains dotPeek if you don't want to pay for Reflector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VS Reflector plugin](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to browse through the framework source code.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has made the source code for most of the .NET framework BCL available for some time, so you can look at it yourself. It is available [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).